# Typescript for mounted enzyme wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a test helper function for an `expect` statement I found myself repeating multiple times. The function looks like:

```js
const exampleHelper = (wrapper: AnyObject): void => {
  return expect(
    wrapper
      .find('[data-test="example"]')
      .first()
      .childAt(0)
      .exists()
    ).toBe(true)
}
```

The function works perfect, but out of curiosity what would the type would be for the `wrapper` being passed. The `wrapper` should expect a mounted wrapper such as:

```js
const wrapper = mount(
  <TestWrapper>
    <ExampleComponent data={mockData} />
  </TestWrapper>
 )
```

I tried using `ReactElement`, but got the following error

```
Property 'find' does not exist on type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'
```

Comment: I don't use react, but can't you just mouse over the `mount` function and see what type it returns?

Answer (score 1):

Your `wrapper` parameter would be `ReactWrapper` and your return should be `void`:

```
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";

const exampleHelper = (wrapper: ReactWrapper): void => {
  expect(
    wrapper.find('[data-test="example"]').first().childAt(0).exists()
  ).toBeTruthy();
};
```

I'd recommend [toBeTruthy](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobetruthy) over `toBe(true)` because [.exists()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/exists.html) is guaranteed to produce a boolean. Also most, if not all, of the assertion methods don't return any result, so returning the expectation is not necessary.

---

If you're trying to write a findByTestId function, I'd recommend defining it within a describe block's `beforeEach` statement, then you won't have to pass in `wrapper` as an argument:

```
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";
import Example from "../index";

describe("Example" => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
  let findByTestId: (id: string) => ReactWrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Example data-test="example-id" />);
    findByTestId = id => wrapper.find(`[data-test='${id}']`);
  })

  it("finds element by test id", () => {
    expect(findByTestId("example-id").exists()).toBeTruthy();
  })
})
```

OR... if you're trying to write a reusable function that be can used in any test file, then you can do something like this:

````
import type { ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";

/**
 * A testing helper function to find an element by 'data-test'.
 *
 * @function findByTestId
 * @param {ReactWrapper} wrapper
 * @param {string} id
 * @returns {ReactWrapper}
 * @example ```findByTestId(wrapper, "id")```
 */
const findByTestId = (wrapper: ReactWrapper, id: string): ReactWrapper => wrapper.find(`[data-test='${id}']`);

export default findByTestId;
````

Then use it in your test file (either `findById` or `findByTestId` way works):

```
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";
import findByTestId from "../../path/to/utils/findByTestId";
import Example from "../index";

describe("Example" => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
  let findById: (id: string) => ReactWrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Example data-test="example-id" />);
    findById = id => findByTestId(wrapper, id);
  })

  it("finds element by test id", () => {
    expect(findByTestId(wrapper, "example-id").exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(findById("example-id").exists()).toBeTruthty();
  })
})
```